# Partial sum $\{\frac{s_m}{s_n}\}$ converge to $1$ implies series converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

Let $s_n$ and $s_m$ be the partial sum of the series $\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty a_k$ with $m<n$ and $a_k > 0$ for all k. If $\{\frac{s_m}{s_n}\}$ converge to $1$, does it imply that the series converges?

Comment: What do you mean by $\{\frac{s_m}{s_n}\}$  converges? When one of $m,n$ is fixed?

Comment: I'm guessing they mean $m=n+1$.

Comment: I mean if there exists a positive integer $N$ such that $|\frac{s_m}{s_n} - 1| < \epsilon$ for all $n>m\geq N$.

Answer (score 2):

If $\frac {s_m} {s_n} \to 1$ as $n,m \to \infty$ then $\ln s_m -\ln s_n \to 0$ which means $(\ln s_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence. Hence it converges to some number $c$. It follows that $s_n \to e^{c}$ so the series is convergent.

Comment: Can you use a $\epsilon$ proof to show that $|\frac{s_m}{s_n} - 1| < \epsilon \implies |\ln{s_m} - \ln{s_n}| < \epsilon$?

Comment: @Mr.Chen Hint: Let $x_n =\frac {s_m} {s_n}$. By MVT $|\ln x_n|=|\ln x_n-\ln 1|=\frac {|1-x_n|} {t_n}$ for some $t_n$ between $x_n$ and $1$. This gives $|\ln x_n| \leq \frac {|1-x_n|} {x_n} \leq  \frac {|1-x_n|} {1-|1-x_n|} <\epsilon$ if $x_n <1$ and $|1-x_n| <\frac {\epsilon} {1+\epsilon}$. The case $x_n \geq 1$ is similar.